# Rewriting equation with modulo

Tags: php, modulo, algebra

I know an event happens on a Monday in any given year. I also know that the event falls between May 25-31 of any given year. If I calculate the type of day May 25th is, I find out that its a Wednesday. But how can I write a script to determine the event will be May 30th?

I'm assigning the days a number: Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, etc...

I have variable A equal to what day May 25th is: A = 4

I have variable B equal to what day the event occurs on: B = 2

I'm setting X equal to how many days I need to add to A to have the correct date.

I wrote this equation that seems to work:

(A + X) % 7 = B

(4 + X) % 7 = 2

I know if I set 5 as X the equation is true, and 5 is how many days I need to add to May 25th to make it May 30th, but how can I rewrite the equation so it is equal to X and not to B?

Comment: Modular arithmetic works much better if you start counting at 0, not 1.

Comment: Do you have to do this with modular arithmetic? PHP's date functions can do it: `strtotime("next Monday", strtotime("May 24, 2017"))`